# Multiple Formula on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.1         2.43
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.26
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
360.5         2.22
362.1         2.18
363.6         2.16
365.2         2.14
```

I want to use the formula

- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 340-345 and add all the reflectance values then added value as r
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 350-355 and add all the reflectance values then added value as i
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 360-365 and add all the reflectance values then added value as n

Formula is

```
2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1))
```

- Output value should be named as tera

Expected Output

```
tera
-2.33333
```

Formula is

```
(r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n)
```

- Output should be named as tera

Expected Output

```
tera
-0.89831
```

Seperate queries for Seperate Formula. Is it possible to apply formula like that in PostgreSQL? Like this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf53d/2)

```
select
  2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) as tera,
  (r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n) as tera2
from
  (
  select
    sum(case when wavelength between 340 and 345 then reflectance end) as r,
    sum(case when wavelength between 350 and 355 then reflectance end) as i,
    sum(case when wavelength between 360 and 365 then reflectance end) as n
  from
    test
  ) vars
```

For multiple tables you can use something like:

```
select
  table_name,
  2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) as tera,
  (r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n) as tera2
from
  (
  select
    table_name,
    sum(case when wavelength between 340 and 345 then reflectance end) as r,
    sum(case when wavelength between 350 and 355 then reflectance end) as i,
    sum(case when wavelength between 360 and 365 then reflectance end) as n
  from
    (
      select 'table 1' as table_name, * from test
      union all
      select 'table 2', * from test
      union all
      select 'table 3', * from test      
      union all
      select 'table 4', * from test  
    ) as all_tables
  group by
    table_name
  ) vars
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf53d/5)

You just need to modify table names to your actual names and repeat `union all` as many times as you need.

Comment: Sir without sum the values can i apply formula as mentioned above in my question is it possible?

Comment: You should start a new question for this. I already answered two different questions and I do not intend to answer another here. Revert your changes to previous state and please start new question. In your new question you should also specify what you mean by first, second, third value as there is no guaranteed implicit order of rows. Maybe you have some column with id or timestamp?

Comment: Sir I Started the new question MULTIPLE FORMULA EXEXUTION ON DATA - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803777/multiple-formula-exexution-on-data in this link, If i make changes in this one it is showing the column with no values

Comment: My Question reverted to the original stage

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you. I have added the Formula to the same query. If you need them in seperate statement then just past the formulas into to two queries.

```
SELECT
    2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) AS tera,
    (r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n) AS tera2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.wavelength BETWEEN 340 AND 345 THEN tbl.reflectance ELSE 0 END) AS r,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.wavelength BETWEEN 350 AND 355 THEN tbl.reflectance ELSE 0 END) AS i,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.wavelength BETWEEN 360 AND 365 THEN tbl.reflectance ELSE 0 END) AS n
    FROM
        table1 as tbl
) as outertbl
```

the output will be

```
tera                tera2
-2.33333333333335   -0.898305084745763
```

Comment: Sir without sum the values is it possible to do the task i mentioned above?