# MULTIPLE VALUES ON SELECTION

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.1         2.43
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.26
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
360.5         2.22
362.1         2.18
363.6         2.16
365.2         2.14
```

I want to use the formula

- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 340-345 as r
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 350-355 as i
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 360-365 as n

Formula is

```
2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1))
```

- Output value should be named as tera

Expected Output

```
tera
-2.33333
........
........
........
```

Formula is

```
(r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n)
```

- Output should be named as tera

Execution

- Take first value of all three selection and apply formula and create
  output
- Take second , third, fourth value of all the three like that and so on then create
  output as a column

Expected Output

```
tera
-0.89831
........
........
.........
```

Query1:

```
select
  2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) as tera
from
  (
  select
    sum(case when wavelength between 340 and 345 then reflectance end) as r,
    sum(case when wavelength between 350 and 355 then reflectance end) as i,
    sum(case when wavelength between 360 and 365 then reflectance end) as n
  from
    test
  ) vars
```

I tried this Query1,It gives a single value as sum operation performs on that
Query2:

```
SELECT
    2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) AS TERA
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 340 AND 345 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS r,
    CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 350 AND 355 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS i,
    CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 355 AND 360 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS n
    FROM
    deodar
    ) T
```

While i am trying this query2 it is producing so many values, In my data , The provided all three intervals have 3 values only So the output will be only three values
My original data consists of 1024 rows and all three intervals have 25 values, so i want to get output of 25 values only.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Update your question with any attempts you have made.

Comment: suppose i don't get value for n 360-365 for 3 record. then what should be default value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Formula on PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782600/multiple-formula-on-postgresql)

Comment: It would be good if you at least provide data and solution from your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782600/multiple-formula-on-postgresql) and link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf53d/2) I prepared for you  as this is only a slightly modified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf53d/9):

```
select
  2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) as tera,
  (r-(2*i)-n)/(r+(2*i)-n) as tera2
from

    (select wavelength, reflectance as r, row_number() over(order by wavelength) as rn
     from test where wavelength between 340 and 345) t1
    join 
    (select wavelength, reflectance as i, row_number() over(order by wavelength) as rn
     from test where wavelength between 350 and 355) t2 using (rn)
    join
    (select wavelength, reflectance as n, row_number() over(order by wavelength) as rn
     from test where wavelength between 360 and 365) t3 using (rn)
```

Answer (score 1):

select

2.5*((r-i)/(r+(6*i)-(7.5*n)+1)) AS TERA  from

(

SELECT
  SUM(r) as r,SUM(i) as i,SUM(n)as n,ROW_FLAG

FROM
   (

select

CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN  345 AND 350 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS r,

CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 350 AND 355 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS i,

CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 355 AND 360 THEN reflectance ELSE 0 END AS n   ,

row_number() over (partition by(CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 345 AND 350 THEN 1

WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 350 AND 355 THEN 2

WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 355 AND 360 THEN 3

ELSE 0 END)  order by wavelength ) AS ROW_FLAG

from YOUR_TABLE
 ) T

GROUP BY ROW_FLAG
) T

Comment: @Gooner Check your keyboard. It looks like you have CAPS LOCK pressed

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US!